# I'm in trouble in K-Means using Mapreduce (modified)

Tags: java, mapreduce, k-means, sequencefile

I think my code is not wrong but, it doesn't work correctly.
This is K-means clustering using mapreduce.
(https://github.com/30stm/K-Means-using-mapreduce/tree/master)

Make a dataset using DatasetWriter.java, and make centroids using CreateCentroids.java.
Then, excute KMeansClusteringJob.java

This code works at the first iteration, but It doesn't work from second iteration.
I checked map function and reduce function, I think the problem is reduce function.
(Map function finds closest centroid from each point.
Reduce function calculate new centroid and replace the new one.)
After first iteration, cen.seq (centroid file) is imperfect.

Somebody help me ;)

p.s : I wrote a question about reduce code, my original problem is this one.

Comment: You need a language tag.  If this is java, give it a java tag so the java people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked has a `newCenter.setVector(new double[vectorSize]);` that you probably need before your `newCenter.getVector()`.

Comment: Thanks. I removed that part during modifying codes.

Comment: Not without a chance to look at the new version of your code.  You should probably ask a new question.